# can you not edit a double in a function with a argument?

Tags: java, android

What is really wrong with this?

```
    public void changeElement(String isAdd, double Element, int timesBy, int lowCap) {
    ran = Math.floor(Math.random()*timesBy)+lowCap;
    if(isAdd == "+"){
        if((Element + ran) > 100){
            ran -= ((Element + ran)-100);
        };
        Element += ran;
    }else{
        if((Element - ran) < 0){
            ran -= (ran - Element); 
        };
        Element -= ran;
    };
    Elementi = (int)Element;
    ranI = (int)ran;

}
```

I know the math works because i changed the 'Element' tag to the double i have been using so why does it not change the true double like its meant to.

Comment: use `isAdd.equals("+")` not `==`

Comment: Java is pass by value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume you mean it doesn't change the value of what you pass into the parameter?

If that's the case, Java is `pass by value`, *not* `pass by reference`.

In other words, rather than a reference of your parameter being passed to the method, a copy of the parameter is passed. Your method changes the copy but then once the method ends, the copy goes out of scope and is garbage collected.

**So what's the solution?**

Change the method signature to `double` and return Element. Then set Element to the return value when you call your function.

[Please read this relevant answer as well.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

Comment: "if" that's the case?

Comment: @DavidWallace I interpreted the question the best I could and answered it to the best of my ability. Is there something wrong with that?

Comment: You got it right! thanks it works now. never thought of it like that.

Comment: @GavinMcLean glad to help Gavin. Keep on coding bro, it's a great occupation or hobby